# Select first workday AFTER [Date]

Tags: sql, db2

I need to calculate whether a price quote's `DATE_COMPLETED` is within one working day of `DATE_RECEIVED` by joining to a `FACILITY_CALENDAR` table with a `WORK_DAY_INDICATOR` column.

```
QUOTE_ID | DATE_RECEIVED | DATE_COMPLETED | Expected Result
---------+---------------+----------------+----------------
0001     | 2019-09-18    | 2019-09-20     | FALSE
0002     | 2019-09-19    | 2019-09-20     | TRUE
0003     | 2019-09-20    | 2019-09-23     | TRUE


SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE | WORK_DAY_INDICATOR
-----------------+-------------------
2019-09-18       | Y
2019-09-19       | Y
2019-09-20       | Y
2019-09-21       | N
2019-09-22       | N
2019-09-23       | Y
```

I've come across several posts and articles that compare dates, but what I haven't found is comparing dates where either the first date or second date might not be a workday.

My first thought was to create a loop that incremented on the `SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE` after the `DATE_RECEIVED` until `WORK_DAY_INDICATOR = 'Y'`, but a colleague suggested that I use `MAX()` instead.

My first attempt:

```
(SELECT 
  MAX(FACILITY_CALENDAR.SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE) AS MAXDATE,
  PRICE_QUOTE.DATE_RECEIVED,
  PRICE_QUOTE.DATE_COMPLETED,
  PRICE_QUOTE.QUOTE_ID
FROM FACILITY_CALENDAR AS FC
LEFT JOIN PRICE_QUOTE AS PQ ON (PQ.DATE_RECEIVED + 1 day) = FC.SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE
WHERE FC.WORK_DAY_INDICATOR = 'Y'
GROUP BY
  PRICE_QUOTE.DATE_RECEIVED,
  PRICE_QUOTE.DATE_COMPLETED,
  PRICE_QUOTE.QUOTE_ID)
```

This code is giving dates where the `WORK_DAY_INDICATOR = 'N'`.

Then I tried using this article's example below, but I need to create a join between the `PRICE_QUOTE` table and the `FACILITY_CALENDAR`, which goes wrong whether I join on `DATE_RECEIVED` or `DATE_COMPLETED`.

https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-date.php

```
SELECT ord_num, ord_amount, ord_date, agent_code
FROM orders
WHERE ord_date=(
SELECT MAX(ord_date) FROM orders WHERE agent_code='A002');
```

I expect that when a `DATE_RECEIVED` is a Friday and the facility's next workday is Monday, then the `MAXDATE` should be Monday.

Addendum: Not all weekdays are work days; some are holidays, so it doesn't work to use days of the week or number of days in a weekend to separate the work days from non-work-days.

Comment: I find it hard to believe this compiled, as `PQ.DATE_RECEIVED + 1 day` is not valid syntax. Did you mean `PQ.DATE_RECEIVED + INTERVAL '1' DAY`? Also, please **edit your question** and provide example data *in the question* for each of your tables which demonstrates the issues you've reported. Thanks.

Comment: I got the language wrong. It's actually DB2 SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH 
PRICE_QUOTE (QUOTE_ID, DATE_RECEIVED, DATE_COMPLETED) AS
(
VALUES
  ('0001', DATE('2019-09-18'), DATE('2019-09-20'))
, ('0002', DATE('2019-09-19'), DATE('2019-09-20'))
, ('0003', DATE('2019-09-20'), DATE('2019-09-23'))
)
, FACILITY_CALENDAR (SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE, WORK_DAY_INDICATOR) AS
(
VALUES
  (DATE('2019-09-18'), 'Y')
, (DATE('2019-09-19'), 'Y')
, (DATE('2019-09-20'), 'Y')
, (DATE('2019-09-21'), 'N')
, (DATE('2019-09-22'), 'N')
, (DATE('2019-09-23'), 'Y')
)
*/
SELECT Q.*
, CASE 
    WHEN 
    (
    SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM FACILITY_CALENDAR C 
    WHERE C.WORK_DAY_INDICATOR = 'Y' 
    AND C.SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE BETWEEN Q.DATE_RECEIVED AND Q.DATE_COMPLETED
    ) > 2 
    THEN 'FALSE'
    ELSE 'TRUE'
  END AS EXPECTED_RESULT
FROM PRICE_QUOTE Q
;
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't mention that not all weekdays are work days. I've edited my question to include this detail.

Comment: My query doesn’t rely on weekdays. It relies on your `FACILITY_CALENDAR` table, where the exact status of all dates is expected disregarding the date status according to the calendar. Have you tried to uncomment the lines commented out and run the query as is? It returns the desired result on all contemporary Db2 versions, but I’m not sure if it works on so very old v4 version...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LEAD` analytic function to get the next working day:

```sql
SELECT PQ.DATE_RECEIVED,
       PQ.DATE_COMPLETED,
       PQ.QUOTE_ID,
       FC.SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE,
       FC.NEXT_SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE,
       CASE
       WHEN PQ.DATE_COMPLETED <= FC.NEXT_SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE
       THEN 'Within 1 working day'
       ELSE 'More than 1 working day'
       END AS within_1_day
FROM   (
  SELECT SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE,
         LEAD( SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE ) OVER ( ORDER BY SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE )
           AS NEXT_SHIFT_BEGIN_DATE
  FROM   FACILITY_CALENDAR
  WHERE  WORK_DAY_INDICATOR = 'Y'
) FC
INNER JOIN PRICE_QUOTE PQ
ON ( PQ.DATE_COMPLETED = FC.SHIFT_DEGIN_DATE )
```

*(Note: This is untested as you've not provided any sample data but it should give you the idea of how to apply it to your data.)*